# How to add a server to RallyDev Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rally

I am using the RallyDev eclipse plugin. How do I add a server to the Add a Task Repository Server drop-down? We run Rally on our own server, but I am not able to add the server.

I am using Eclipse Juno, and Rally Plugin version 3.4.

[image: Add a Task Repository screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Navigate to your eclipse installation directory.
2. Go into the "plugins" directory and locate the directory for the Rally plugin.  For me the directory was named `com.rallydev.mylyn.ui_1.5.11.201207192017`
3. Open the plugin.xml file in the editory of your choice. and add the following:

   ```
   <plugin>
        ...
        <extension point="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core.templates">
         ...
            <repository
               label="[However you want to label your server]"
               repositoryKind="rally"
               urlRepository="https://uri/to/your/server/">
            </repository>
         ...
      </extension>
   </plugin>
   ```
4. Save the file. And close eclipse if it is already running. Notice I state 'close' not 'restart'.
5. At the command prompt/terminal navigate to your eclipse installation directory.
6. Start eclipse from the command line with the arg -clean. For example:
       C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean

On your next attempt to add a Rally Task Repo, you will see your label in the server dropdown.
You may need to adjust your 'urlRepository' according to however the ALM is installed.  You will know that you need to adjust the URL because the 'Validate Settings' will fail. Just make sure that you restart from the command line with the -clean argument after any plugin.xml modifications.

[image: After plugin.xml modifications screenshot]

Comment: This works for Eclipse Indigo also again using Rally plugin version 3.4.